# OpenCV - C++ - DMatch - Is the descriptor index the same as it's corresponding keypoint index?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compute disparity for corresponding keypoints in two epipolar stereo images. 
I know how to get keypoints, descriptors and then compute DMatch, but then I'm using this simple operation to get disparity and I'm not sure if it's ok:

```
float disparity = keypointsLeft[matches[i].queryIdx].pt.x - keypointsRight[matches[i].trainIdx].pt.x;
```

(matches was defined as: `vector <DMatch> matches` and then computed)

Why I'm not sure?
OpenCV documentation 2.4.12 says:

1) for **DescriptorExtractor::compute**

```
void DescriptorExtractor::compute(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors) const
```

*keypoints – Input collection of keypoints. Keypoints for which a descriptor cannot be computed **are removed and the remaining ones may be reordered**. Sometimes new keypoints can be added, for example: SIFT duplicates a keypoint with several dominant orientations (for each orientation).*

2) for **DMatch**

*Class for matching keypoint descriptors: query descriptor index, train descriptor index, train image index, and distance between descriptors.*

The problem is: Is the descriptor index the same as it's corresponding keypoint index, when as we can read the **descriptors vector doesn't contain the data for each detected keypoint** ?

I would check it for myself, but I have no idea how to do this... Maybe there is someone who also wondered about this issue.
My application is working and it looks fine, but it doesn't mean that it's ok...

Comment: The keypoints that cannot be computed will be removed before computing the descriptors. The size of the descriptors will always be equal to the size of the output keypoints vector. (from my experience)

Comment: Thanks, I've prepared the raport and it's as you said. After computing descriptors (BRISK extractor), vector of keypoints changes and some keypoints are removed from vector. That's why the keypoint vector size before computing descriptors and after that varies.