# Is there a way to store feature matches in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am doing image features extraction using SIFT in opencv. The matching takes a really long time to run, and I want to store the matching object into a file and load whenever possible. Is there a way to do this? It seems that storing keypoints and descriptors are possible, but I didn't find any useful information about the matches.

**Update1**:

The information I wanted to store is the following:

```
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

### Want magically to store the information of the variable matches
```

**Update2**:

I didn't realize that the object DMatch contains different layers of information. Also, [since](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324103/13331781) DMatch only stores the indices of matched keypoints, their distance and the index of the image, trying to save a DMatch file may not be the best idea. I am now trying to extract those information and save the indices instead. As it is possible to store the keypoints and descriptors, I may be able to reconstruct the matches after loading the match indices.

Comment: I think there is an example [here](https://linuxtut.com/en/8416b6f255946c9f4fb5/). What have you tried so far? If you can't find a solution, please post a small code sample, with two small images, and let us know the specific information you like to save.

Comment: `cv::FileStorage` is supposed to be able to handle KeyPoint objects and vectors of them. I've never used it from python but give it a look

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for the information! But I didn't find anything useful, or I couldn't make those functions work. Maybe the Dmatch has too much information to store?

Comment: @Rotem  I don't think that the example helps anything, but thank you for the information.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d74/tutorial_file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html so it seems that doesn't "just work" in python, or isn't implemented. so you will have to write a function that takes the *three values* of a `DMatch` and turns them into python dictionaries. then you can write that as json or xml or whatever, with python's own libraries or with FileStorage and `startWriteStruct`